# How to upload big file (>2GB) in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, file-upload, sharepoint-2013

For some reason, I have to upload big files (2GB or more each) to sharepoint server. I know that sharepoint just limit the size up to 2gb so I have written a custom webpart to upload the files straight to server's disk but still no luck. I tried to modify maxAllowedContentLength, maxRequestLength, anything from webconfig and IIS (7.0) setting . Are there any ways to do it?
Thanks for any advices and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: This might be a good reason to upgrade to SharePoint 2016, which has a default limit of 2GB which is configurable to up to 10GB per file.

Answer (score 2):

What you are requesting is not supported by Microsoft. Please refer to the TechNet article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cc262787.aspx#ContentDB

"The default file size is 50 MB, which can be increased to a maximum of 2 GB. You can fit 100 files in each content database. Multiple site collections can share a single content database. Each site collection needs to be fully stored in a single content database.
We strongly recommended limiting the size of content databases to 200 GB, except when the circumstances in the following rows in this table apply.
If you are using Remote BLOB Storage (RBS), the total volume of remote BLOB storage and metadata in the content database must not exceed the 200GB limit."

I would really question why you would need to upload such large content! Your farm will break down eventually..